# How to use SYSIN?

Tags: jcl, zos

I've an exercise that I need to complete and execute the necessary applications to
distribute the information about the transactions of credit cards business, with the ultimate goal of showing at a web page the confirmations of transactions.

My current step:
"The JCL that runs the publishing application must have a DD
called SYSIN to allow the application to read from the publication
ZOS.CONTEST3.TXNS file using STDIN file handle."

ZOS.CONTEST3.TXNS contains information about the operations to be published.

I just need to implement a DD statement called SYSIN pointing to 'ZOS.CONTEST3.TXNS' like this?

```
//SYSIN DD DSN=ZOS.CONTEST3.TXNS,DISP=SHR
```

JCL code:

```
//EXECPUB JOB MSGCLASS=H
//PUBLISH  EXEC PGM=PUBAPP,REGION=1024K,        
//         PARM='MQ03 USER_ID'                  
//STEPLIB  DD DSN=USER_ID.PRTTHREE.LOAD,DISP=SHR
//         DD DSN=WMQ.V701.SCSQLOAD,DISP=SHR    
//         DD DSN=WMQ.V701.SCSQANLE,DISP=SHR    
//         DD DSN=WMQ.V701.SCSQAUTH,DISP=SHR    
//STDOUT   DD SYSOUT=*                          
//STDERR   DD SYSOUT=*                          
//SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=*
```

I've submitted the job and this is the LOG in SDSF (without SYSIN):
(In "ST    Status of jobs" no have the submitted job...)

```
SDSF SYSLOG   6203.101 MVST MVST 06/07/2014 0W   30042      COLUMNS   1  80   
COMMAND INPUT ===>                                            SCROLL ===> PAGE

N 0200000 ZTT1     14158 04:13:08.90 JOB06616 00000281  $HASP100 EXECPUB  ON INTRDR                            FROM TSU06615  
S                                                       USER_ID                 
N 0000000 ZTT1     14158 04:13:08.90 JOB06616 00000290  IRR010I  USERID USER_ID  IS ASSIGNED TO THIS JOB.          
N 0020000 ZTT1     14158 04:13:08.94 JOB06616 00000281  ICH70001I USER_ID  LAST ACCESS AT 03:58:54 ON SATURDAY, JUNE 7, 2014  
N 4000000 ZTT1     14158 04:13:08.94 JOB06616 00000090  $HASP373 EXECPUB  STARTED - INIT 1    - CLASS A - SYS MVST  
N 0000000 ZTT1     14158 04:13:08.94 JOB06616 00000090  IEF403I EXECPUB - STARTED - TIME=04.13.08   
N 0020000 ZTT1     14158 04:13:08.97 JOB06616 00000281  CSV003I REQUESTED MODULE PUBAPP   NOT FOUND  
N 00A0000 ZTT1     14158 04:13:08.97 JOB06616 00000090  CSV028I ABEND806-04  JOBNAME=EXECPUB   STEPNAME=PUBLISH   
N 0000000 ZTT1     14158 04:13:08.97          00000290  IEA989I SLIP TRAP ID=X806 MATCHED.  JOBNAME=EXECPUB , ASID=002E.     

M 0020000 ZTT1     14158 04:13:08.97 JOB06616 00000281  IEA995I SYMPTOM DUMP OUTPUT 402  
D                                         402 00000281  SYSTEM COMPLETION CODE=806  REASON CODE=00000004 
D                                         402 00000281   TIME=04.13.08  SEQ=02152  CPU=0000  ASID=002E 
D                                         402 00000281   PSW AT TIME OF ERROR  070C1000   813DAC4E  ILC 2  INTC 0D  
D                                         402 00000281     NO ACTIVE MODULE FOUND
D                                         402 00000281     NAME=UNKNOWN         
D                                         402 00000281     DATA AT PSW  013DAC48 - 8400181E  0A0D18FB  180C181D  
D                                         402 00000281     AR/GR 0: 99FE0D16/00001E00   1: 00000000/84806000     
D                                         402 00000281           2: 00000000/00000000   3: 00000000/00000000  
D                                         402 00000281           4: 00000000/00000000   5: 00000000/006FF548  
D                                         402 00000281           6: 00000000/000000FF   7: 00000000/00000000  
D                                         402 00000281           8: 00000000/006B1250   9: 00000000/013DB138   
D                                         402 00000281           A: 00000000/00000000   B: 00000000/00000000  
D                                         402 00000281           C: 00000000/00000000   D: 00000000/006B1250 
D                                         402 00000281           E: 00000000/84806000   F: 00000000/00000004   
E                                         402 00000281   END OF SYMPTOM DUMP    
M 0000000 ZTT1     14158 04:13:08.98 JOB06616 00000090  IEF450I EXECPUB PUBLISH - ABEND=S806 U0000 REASON=00000004 403
E                                         403 00000090          TIME=04.13.08   

N 0004000 ZTT1     14158 04:13:08.98 JOB06616 00000290  -                                         --TIMINGS (MINS.)--   
S                                                        ----PAGING COUNTS---   
N 0004000 ZTT1     14158 04:13:08.98 JOB06616 00000290  -JOBNAME  STEPNAME PROCSTEP    RC   EXCP    CPU    SRB  CLOCK   SERV  PG  
S                                                          PAGE   SWAP    VIO SWAPS STEPNO     
N 0004000 ZTT1     14158 04:13:08.98 JOB06616 00000290  -EXECPUB           PUBLISH  *S806     18    .00    .00    .00   2248   0  
S                                                             0      0      0     0     1       
N 0000000 ZTT1     14158 04:13:08.98 JOB06616 00000090  IEF404I EXECPUB - ENDED - TIME=04.13.08 
N 0004000 ZTT1     14158 04:13:08.98 JOB06616 00000290  -EXECPUB  ENDED.  NAME-                     TOTAL CPU TIME=   .00  TOTAL 
S                                                        ELAPSED TIME=   .00    
N 4000000 ZTT1     14158 04:13:08.98 JOB06616 00000090  $HASP395 EXECPUB  ENDED 
N C000000 ZTT1     14158 04:13:09.00          00000090  $HASP309 INIT 1    INACTIVE ******** C=A       
MR0000000 ZTT1     14158 04:20:44.63 STARTUP  00000090  $HASP003 RC=(52),D 411  
DR                                        411 00000090  $HASP003 RC=(52),D JQ  - NO SELECTABLE ENTRIES FOUND     
ER                                        411 00000090  $HASP003           MATCHING SPECIFICATION
```

Thanks for your attention!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem with running this jobstep is here:

```
CSV003I REQUESTED MODULE PUBAPP   NOT FOUND  
CSV028I ABEND806-04  JOBNAME=EXECPUB   STEPNAME=PUBLISH
```

This means that PUBAPP is not in any loadlibrary you have specified on the `//STEPLIB DD`.

It may be: a program failed to compile/link/bind; it was linked/bound to the wrong library; the STEPLIB contains the wrong library; the STEPLIB contains a missing library.

Remember this is a contest, and there are probably little traps along the way.

Comment: Hello Bill! I found the problem.
The problem is when I compile the program. I'm sure the JCL has no flaws in code. When I run the JCL that will compile the program, should create a member in my dataset USER_ID.PRTTHREE.LOAD with the result of the compilation of the program, but nothing happens.. And my job doesn't appears at ST(Status of Jobs) option of SDSF after submitted, as usually happens... Now I can only see the LOG option and I see no errors(apparently).
This is my JCL that will compile my program:
http://pastebin.com/yuxXC7M0

Comment: Throughout the contest, I came across several instabilities within the Z/OS. I find it strange because when compiling another program with a similar code, it flowed normally.